# Postgres, jsonb

Tags: java, postgresql

how can I write query:

```
where data @> '[{"id": "1884595530"}]'
```

in java, assuming that 1884595530 is a query parameter. I tried

```
String sql = "where data @> '[{\"id\": :id}]'"
```

but it ends with error:

`enter code here`Expected "," or "]", found ":".

Comment: Do you mean `WHERE id = 1884595530`?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you need to make your json string a list/array. Is the data field jsonb? If so, you should be able to do the following:

```
where data @> '{"id":"1884595530"}'::jsonb
```

If id is an integer instead of string, you may need to do this one:

```
where data @> '{"id":1884595530}'::jsonb
```

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=123b96326f463fbdc2e670a5146e2c0d